# assimp issue exporting model textures

Tags: assimp

I'm trying to export via assimp command line tool two models: one from .fbx (2013) and one from .lwo both to .obj file format.

However I'm not able to extract the textures from the original files.

The command that I perform is:

assimp export INPUT_FILE.xxx OUTPUT_FILE.obj -cts, -gsn, -jiv, -icl, -lbw, -rrm, -slm, -tri, -guv, -sbpt, -fd, -fiv, -fi, -vds -om

The model are:

https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/cubesat-1RU

and

https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/acrimsat

previously converted to the .fbx 2013 file format via FbxConverterUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment we do not export the embedded textures as far as I know. We opened an issue to get this fixed.